# Повторяющиеся слова в `.txt`

Tags: c#

Как найти все слова, которые повторяются в `.txt` файле, и вывести их на экран ?

Comment: Пример файла хотя бы указали

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 
1
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 15):

```
File.ReadAllText("file.txt")
    .Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .GroupBy(w => w)
    .Where(w => w.Count() > 1)
    .Select(w => w.Key)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Красиво выглядит.

Answer (score 3):

Можно например вот таким образом:

```
string[] input = "1 1 1 2 3 4".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//string[] input = File.ReadAllText("file.txt").Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string[] output = (from word in input where Array.IndexOf(input, word) != Array.LastIndexOf(input, word) select word).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>();
var strings = File.ReadAllText("file.txt")
        .Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Where(x => !hash.Add(x)).Distinct().ToArray();
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Метод `HashSet<>.Add()` возвращает `false`, если элемент уже есть в коллекции.

Comment: Нужно еще учесть вариант, при котором повторяющийся элемент встретится, например, 5 раз. Ваш код в этом случае выведет его 4 раза. Что-то типа `Distinct` надо делать...

Comment: @Андрей да, точно

Comment: Кстати, другой интересный вариант - завести еще один `HashSet` и добавлять в него все элементы, которые не добавились в первый - это и будут повторяющиеся + без дублей сразу. Возможно это будет быстрее работать

Comment: @Андрей `Distinct` внутри это и делает

Comment: Да, действительно, посмотрел исходник